# verifying imagemagick is installed through browser url

Tags: imagemagick

we installed **imagemagick** in our server using `pecl install imagick` is there any way we can check it is succesfuly installed or not in server ?

can we paste any url in browser and check whether it is installed or not?

please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

**edit**

we got this result, after following below answer

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called `phpinfo.php` on your server (in the root, for example) and put this in the file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Open your browser and go to the phpinfo.php file (e.g. http://myserver.com/phpinfo.php) and it will tell you everything about the PHP installation and any modules installed/available.

Alternatively, if `phpinfo` doesn't show anything then you can get more information from your server by querying (command line) `convert -version`.

**Be careful putting this file/info on a production server as it will tell anyone pretty much everything about your system and the platform/architecture/server software you're using. Only use it for your own information purposes and then delete/move the file away from your doc root.**

Comment: This is demo site. please check link and inform me i searched with word "image" and "magic" using CTRL + F , but i didt found anything related to that imagemagick word.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer but you will need access to the server command line to run `convert -version` - I assume you're running a Linux server?

Comment: if you check the link and inform me, it will be really helpfull for me.

Comment: we have something like this : https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/503301/3974813/BtIlNVawQhZ0byO/imagemagic.png  do you think its installed ?

Comment: It means you have ImageMagick installed...